# How to query where a package was installed from on linux?

Tags: linux, package-management

Like most linux distributions today, I use more than one package source for all of my applications on my arch-linux setup. (eg pacman, aur, snap, flathub etc.) when I need to update a specific app, I always need to check every package source if it was the source I installed my application with. Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: Write a script to do it. Take the commands you use to check each package source and put them in a .sh file or as a function in bashrc/zshrc. Perhaps just try updating from all sources and redirect to /dev/null (however this has potential to cause issues as you may accidentally install unwanted software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (note: I haven't tested this, it might require alteration, but is a good start. Feel free to edit this with a working version) in `~/.bashrc` [you'll have to run it with `sudo`]

```bsh
func update() {
if [[ pacman -Qs $1 > /dev/null ]]; then
    pacman -S $1
else if [[ yay -Ss $1 | grep -q "Installed" ]]; then
    yay -S $1
else if [[ snap list | grep -q $1 ]]; then
    snap refresh $1
else if [[ flatpak list | grep -q $1 ]]; then
    flatpak update $1
fi
}
```

Comment: Even though it would seem to be the best option if there is no known and available solution, I don' t think this will always do. Pacman may include the package name in descriptions of other packages for example.

Comment: @YusufBarışKöse There are certainly ways to avoid that (check the [man page] (https://archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html) for inspiration). The script I gave you was merely a suggestion

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll implement something like this